# Getting the Payer Information in PayPal Classic API

Tags: paypal, go

I am using at the moment the Classic API from PayPal to create a one time payment, however when I called the GetExpressCheckoutDetails, I don't receive any information about the Payer.

Notice: I am using Google Go as a programming language

Answer (score 1):

It depends on when you call GetEC. GetEC (GetExpressCheckoutDetails) **doesn't necessarily** respond with the payer info, because the payer **may not** be present yet.

Payer info and Payer ID are only available once the payer agrees to pay (he/she signs into PP and fills in the right info and clicks the Continue or Pay button), which means in this case you'd be calling GetEC **AFTER** the payer agrees to pay and gets back to your system for DoEC. This way GetEC will give you payer info.

Here is GetEC doc:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetExpressCheckoutDetails_API_Operation_NVP/